# Switch ignore timestamp option dynamically in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode

I want to use some variations of ignoring timestamp options in org-agenda.

For example, I want to have custom agenda command enumerates

- TODOs Scheduled today
- TODOs tagged some tag only within future 2 weeks
- all TODOs regardless of timestamps

Are there some good way to realize this? (I imagine doing like let-ting org-agenda-ignore-* variables in each custom search options.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done using `tags`/`tags-todo` property searches.  You can search for schedule/deadline/timestamp information using the `SCHEDULED`, `DEADLINE` and `TIMESTAMP` properties.  The TODO state is in the `TODO` property.  Dates relative to "now" can be specified using org's `<+nd>` syntax to mean "n days from today".  Your first two examples can be done using this method:

- TODOs Scheduled today --- `+SCHEDULED="<+0d>"`
- TODOs tagged some tag only within future 2 weeks --- `+sometag+TIMESTAMP<=<+14d>`

The third example is the built-in `t` agenda that lists all TODO items.  You can recreated it by searching for `+TOOD={.*}` (`.*` being a regular expression that matches anything, so this matches any TODO state).  By default this excludes and "done" TODO state.

Comment: Still being through try and error, I've found the way to go. Thanks!